# get join table's all rows with collection magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, model, join

I am fetching a collection (of user table), that is retrieving correctly. Now I have one more table (ex.- address) that has multiple row related collection table primary key. 
I want to fetch them all with collection query.

Like -  If I print the collection object data via -> $obj->getData() then 
It is returning data like this

```
Array=>(
[id] => 1   //====Primary key of user table 
[name] => xyz
[marks] => 85
```

)

But The way I want is  - return data should be like  -

```
Array=>(
[id] => 1   //====Primary key of user table 
[name] => xyz
[marks] => 85
[address] => Array(          //=====Data from related address table========
                1 => (
                    [row_id] => 1
                    [house_no] => 45
                    [id] => 1   //=====Forign Key of user table
                ),
                2 => (
                    [row_id] => 6
                    [house_no] => 45
                    [id]=> 1    //=====Forign Key of user table
                ),
            )
```

)

Can anyone let me know how I can achieve this. Because I tried with `$this->getSelect()->joinLeft()` but it works if related table have only one row .

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your array how do you want?

Comment: I have modified my question to make it more clear. Plz check again.